# Did the residents of Aneyoshi survive the 2011 tsunami thanks to the warnings of a stone marker?

Tags: japan, natural-disasters

According to [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidbressan/2021/03/11/century-old-tsunami-stones-saved-lives-in-the-tohoku-earthquake-of-2011/?sh=2443da3a1fd3):

> In Aneyoshi, a small village on Japan’s northeastern coast, all the inhabitants survived the tsunami of 2011 by climbing to higher ground, following the warnings of a stone marker. The tsunami stone was erected here after a tsunami destroyed the village in 1933, leaving only four survivors behind.

The questions are:

1. Did *all* inhabitants of Aneyoshi survive the tsunami?
2. Did they climb to higher ground because of the warnings on the stone marker?
3. Were tsunami survival rates different in nearby villages that didn't have a similar stone marker?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's *kind of* right.

According to [other](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1379242/Japan-tsunami-Mystic-stone-tides-highest-point-saved-Aneyoshi-deadly-wave.html) [sources](https://atlasobscura.com/places/tsunami-stones) the Aneyoshi monument is not a common "tsunami hazard" sign. Instead, it prohibits building homes below the marked point, and, apparently, after the stone was erected (after another, earlier tsunami; different sources mention different years), survivors moved the location of the village to a higher ground, and "the village credits that with saving the village from another tsunami in 1960". Looking it up on Google Maps, the village indeed is situated higher than the monument.

And the [village did survive the 2011 tsunami](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/21/world/asia/21stones.html) relatively intact. Not all inhabitants survived, though:

> The mother, Mihoko Aneishi, 36, had rushed to take her children out of
> school right after the earthquake. Then she made the fatal mistake of
> driving back through low-lying areas just as the tsunami hit.

A significant hit to the village's population of 34.

So as to your questions:

1. not everyone survived, but the village itself was untouched - ["while Aneyoshi Bay had the highest runup (38.9 m) in the 2011 tsunami, the stone was about 10 m above the inundation zone, and no houses in Aneyoshi Village
   were flooded"](https://www.eeri.org/images/archived/wp-content/uploads/Tohoku_Japan_March_11_2011_EERI_LFE_ERI_ITST_Tsunami.pdf);
2. technically yes, but it happended decades before 2011.
3. apparently, the Aneyoshi marker is unique in that it prohibits building below it; usually, such markers simply denote safe zones for evacuation. That said, [there were ~4000 fatalities in the Iwate prefecture](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3700238/) during the tsunami, and this particular village was untouched - the only fatalities among the residents happened when they were outside it.

An important distinction would be that modern inhabitants of the village were kept aware of the warnings recorded on the marker. [This study](https://www.oecd-nea.org/upload/docs/application/pdf/2020-01/rwm-r2014-4.pdf) mentions another village in the affected area, Murohama, which was located in the tsunami strike zone. The tsunami warning tower there was destroyed in the earthquake, but the villagers still evacuated to a higher ground, and not to the closest hill, which houses another stone with an inscription recounting how villagers hiding on this hill were caught in a tsunami because the hill was too low. The study notes that these were the only locales where the stone warnings entered the folklore and were commonly known, and compares them to other cases where similar markers were forgotten:

> For instance, after the earthquake people in Kesennuma, a village
> close to Aneyoshi, returned to their houses in the low-lying areas,
> although messages on stone markers warned: “If earthquake comes,
> beware of tsunami” and “choose life over your possessions and
> valuables” (Macan-Markar, 2013).

[This article](https://www.economist.com/open-future/2019/12/06/were-designed-to-make-bad-choices-but-heres-what-we-can-do) offers an interesting hypothesis: the markers in Aneyoshi and Murohama are specific, offering practical advice such as "don't build here, build higher" and "don't go to this hill to hide from tsunami, find a higher place". They are also linked in public consciousness to specific incidents from which these warnings were borne. Most of the stones have more abstract warnings, such as "beware of tsunami", which are easily forgotten. Disaster-prevention training focused more on modern warning systems, which in many areas were rendered inoperable, and the infrastructure was designed for more common tsunamis, with breakwalls that were too low and evacuation centers in several cases located in the zones hit by the one-in-a-thousand-years tsunami. The article mentions [Yanosuke Hirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yanosuke_Hirai), a Japanese engineer known for his insistence on the importance of taking highly precautionary protective measures against earthquakes and tsunamis. He is said to have often made reference to the great Jogan tsunami of 869, which reportedly travelled 7 kilometers inland from the coast and even reached the Sengan Shinto shrine in Iwanuma, his birth town. Hirai took part in the design of Onagawa Nuclear Power Plant and is recorded as being the only member of the project team who had insisted on making the plant's tsunami breakwall 14.8 meters tall; others considered 12 meters to be sufficient. Onagawa NPP was twice as close to the epicenter of the 2011 earthquake as the infamous Fukushima Plant, but managed to survive both the earthquake and the following tsunami without any significant damage.

Sources:

1. "Preservation of Records, Knowledge and Memory across Generations (RK&M).
   Markers - Reflections on Intergenerational Warnings in the Form of Japanese Tsunami Stones" - OECD Nuclear Energy Agency, 2014 ([pdf](https://www.oecd-nea.org/upload/docs/application/pdf/2020-01/rwm-r2014-4.pdf))
2. "Learning from Earthquakes. The Japan Tohoku Tsunami of March 11, 2011" - EERI Special Earthquake Report — November 2011 ([pdf](https://www.eeri.org/images/archived/wp-content/uploads/Tohoku_Japan_March_11_2011_EERI_LFE_ERI_ITST_Tsunami.pdf))
3. Nakahara S., Ichikawa M, "Mortality in the 2011 Tsunami in Japan" - Journal of Epidemiology, 2013; 23(1): pp70–73 ([link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3700238/))
4. Fackler M., “Tsunami Warnings, Written in Stone.” - The New York Times, 21 Apr. 2011 ([link](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/21/world/asia/21stones.html))
5. “The mystic stone at tsunami tide's highest point that saved tiny Japanese village from the deadly wave” - Daily Mail Online, 21 Apr. 2011 ([link](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/04/21/world/asia/21stones.html))
6. “We’re designed to make bad choices but here’s what we can do” - The Economist, 6 Dec. 2019 ([link](https://www.economist.com/open-future/2019/12/06/were-designed-to-make-bad-choices-but-heres-what-we-can-do))

Comment: Also worth noting that they didn't actually "climb to higher ground".  This implies that they saw the tsunami coming *in the moment* and fled for the hills, when in fact, they'd spent years or decades resettling on higher ground.  The way it's worded it looks like it happened a lot faster than it probably did.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I recall hearing about an island where there was a local saying that you should run for higher ground when the tide goes out unexpectedly.  The story claimed that (at least some) people who heeded this warning survived but on other similar islands people started collecting fish instead.  There's probably a lot of these stories and it would be easy to mix them up.

Comment: @JimmyJames agreed, which is why third question was about a comparison to towns without such a stone marker. If there's indeed a strong correlation between having a stone marker and local survival rates, then the implication of the article is indeed correct.

Comment: Such advice to head for higher ground when there's a quake (and not wait for it to finish) are common in areas of Alaska, IIRC. They were mostly put up after the megaquake of 1964. The geology there is such that you can get flash tsunamis in fjords rather quickly.

Comment: Does the stone "warn against" or "prohibit"?

Comment: @JonathanReez So, basically, you want a study of efficacy of [these signs](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/E-Bernard-2/publication/6940480/figure/fig2/AS:280646577606656@1443922766588/Tsunami-hazard-zone-warning-sign-at-Rockaway-Beach-Oregon.png)? Because the vast majority of japanese stone markers are just an old-timey example of these. Aneyoshi marker was interesting specifically because the wording of the warning was unique and the village actually stuck with its new location - it is not unusual for people to move back to the danger zone between tsunamis.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov ideally yes, as that's the claim in all the articles about the stones. But a quick confirmation (or refutation) could also be done by looking at the mortality stats of a few neighboring villages without such a sign.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd according to [this article](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/century-old-warnings-against-tsunamis-dot-japans-coastline-180956448/) on Smithsonian Magazine website the inscription reads "High dwellings are the peace and harmony of our descendants. Remember the calamity of the great tsunamis. Do not build any homes below this point." Can't attest to the accuracy of the translation, since I can't read Japanese, but the article has a high-rez photo of the marker.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov many thanks, and please note that I'm not attempting to criticise your excellent answer. So it was an... admonition? rather than a statute.

Comment: While a stone marker may kind of make sense in 1933, I think it's somewhat irrelevant where you have modern legally-enforced zoning laws and tsunami inundation maps. One should compare this to a community where such measures were taken.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Looking at the image, it is a very abrupt "Do **NOT** build". See [this discussion on Japanese SO](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1585/5509) - the stone has 建てるな (don't build), and the discussion is about the な verb ending. Also, the [Wikimedia source image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E5%A4%A7%E6%B4%A5%E6%B3%A2%E8%A8%98%E5%BF%B5%E7%A2%91.JPG) has more information.

Comment: @JimmyJames I thought by 2011 if the ocean disappears unexpectedly then run for high ground wasn't so much "local sayings" and more "scientific understanding and disaster awareness taught at a young age". Like in tornado prone areas we have tornado drills in school.

Comment: @user3067860 I can't say what exists along those lines in every country with a coastline at risk for tsunami.  I doubt that it's exactly the same in Micronesia and Japan, for example.  All I am relaying is what I read/heard in the past.

Comment: @JonathanReez added a section on the efficacy of stone markers. The report I used is under 1 in the sources.

Comment: This is an amazing answer now!

Comment: @user3067860 you're not wrong, but not all people in tsunami-threatened zone would be able to see the ocean retreat. It is mentioned in reports that in several cases  in zones with damaged tsunami warning systems people assumed this was a common earthquake, and evacuated to regular earthquake shelter zones - which were not quite as far from their homes, but also located in the inundation zone.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I was just replying to the one comment about a "local saying to run when the tide goes out unexpectedly".